# Weird view of ImageView with border

Tags: android, imageview, border

I want to put a border for this image with padding of 4dp but when I set the background to the color I want I get all that black border on top and bottom. How can I get rid of that so I properly set the border?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question do not know if I have really got what you want

Take a linear layout and wrap the imageview inside the linear layout then, give background color to linear layout whatever you want and in image view give margin whatever width you want for border

```
    <ScrollView>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="@string/dealer_picker" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/dealer_picker" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#1E1E1E">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mapView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:MARGINHERE SAY 10 dp or whatever />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/adresa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />  
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Not working. The big black border from top and bottom is still there

Comment: try height fillparent instead and tell me

Comment: or do one thing simply try image to fitxy

Comment: see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html just need to android:scaletype = fitxy there may be some error wd syntax please see

Comment: Changes the image to square and scales it really weird with fitXY. Not good either

Comment: do not know what you are doing dude this should fix your problem you are doing something wrong just go to graphical view and stretch your image as you want

Comment: I can't stretch the image because is an mapView, for every item of the spinner selected it shows another image. The image width is too large, so the rest of the image which is out of view gets added by a black screen on top of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to add: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to ImageView

Comment: I have the exact problem but the trick doesn't work for me :(